# Connecting To WebSockets And Topics Through Python

Tags: python, websocket

I have a middleware layer that would take the place of my websocket server also, I have some clients not in JS but in Python that would need to connect to a particular topic and send some data.

Now, my question would be: Where I could find an example in python of connecting to websockets, subscribing to topics and sending messages ?. I am tired of searching but not finding examples or finding but not exactly what I need. Moreover, the client is being applied a "ToPython" migration whereas before it was in java.
Does some knows about a link ?